# Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable to unlock screen or use chrome remote desktop on boot

Tags: server, ssh, google-chrome, lightdm, ubuntu-gnome

I'm trying to set up chrome remote on my Linux machine running ubuntu server 18 and gnome/lightdm on top. I can't figure out how to get chrome remote to work on boot with a lock screen, but it works fine after unlocking and subsequent relocking the screen.

I figured I'd just ssh into my machine to unlock it the first time, but when I run `loginctl unlock-sessions` it doesn't unlock, instead, I get the password input box weirdly overlaying my login icon. However, if I unlock the screen and lock it, running `loginctl unlock-session` does unlock the screen. Is there some setting I'm missing?

Note: I set up chrome remote desktop following this [article](https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e) so that my primary session is the one I would remote into.